# UPDATE ALL WHERE vs COUNT then UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have an inbox system with read/unread messages. I want messages to switch to unread once they are opened.

Each time a message is opened,
Is it better to check whether the message was unread with a COUNT query on message's primary key with a WHERE clause specifying unread = 1, and then if the count is superior to 0, UPDATE the entry to set the read field to 1,

or,

To do an UPDATE query each time with a WHERE clause specifying message's primary key and read field = 0

To be clear, is it better to do this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages WHERE messages.id = 1 AND messages.read = 0
if (query_above > 0)
    UPDATE messages SET messages.read = 1 WHERE messages.id = 1
```

or

```
UPDATE messages SET messages.read = 1 WHERE messages.id = 1 AND messages.read = 0
```

I'm not willing to find a better way to do this in this case ; this is a pure performance question in an arbitrary situation.

Comment: 2 lookups vs 1 lookup. Should be pretty clear.

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to hyper-optimize this? Do you believe `UPDATE messages SET messages.read = 1 WHERE messages.id = 1` will cause you a problem if `read` happens to already be `1`? Also, is there any possibility that more than one connection might attempt the same operation at the same time, against the same message? Such that counting first could result in you acting on stale information?

Comment: No there is not :) I've been using the 2nd solution since years and I've always wondered if that was the best way to do it as I've seen other peoples do it the other way.

Answer (score 2):

Single query is better. Either way the DB engine is going to have to go through its table, you're saving the overhead of having it report back to your handling application which then sends another query request to change a row the DB engine had just visited (and now has to look up again)

Comment: Well, the thing is that once the message is read, you do an useless UPDATE query when with the other solution do only a COUNT query which costs way less. Am I thinking it right ?

Comment: The overhead on reading the result of the COUNT is much, much bigger than the total runtime of the UPDATE query. It might even be the UPDATE query is faster than the COUNT; that I am not sure on, but reading the result, doing a calculation, and then prepping another query is définately more work than a simple update.

Answer (score 0):

The single query is better for several reasons.  But first, this query:

```
UPDATE messages
    SET messages.read = 1
    WHERE messages.id = 1 AND messages.read = 0;
```

Can be optimized with an index on `messages(id, read)`.  The `read` is not strictly necessary if `id` is already a unique or primary key on the table.

Why is one query better?  First, there is the issue of running multiple queries.  Each has its own overhead, so fewer queries is a bit faster.  There is a more important issue with `count(*)` for testing for existence.  The SQL engine doesn't know that you only care about "0" or "greater than 0", so it actually has to count everything.  A better way to write that query is using `exists`:

```
if exists (select 1 from messages where messages.id = 1 and messages.read = 0)
    UPDATE messages SET messages.read = 1 WHERE messages.id = 1
```

This stops at the first row that matches *and stops processing*.  The `count()` continues processing.

The third reason is race conditions.  In a multi-threaded application, something could change between the `if` and the `update`.  This is the strongest reason for using one query.  One query is not only faster, but it is more correct.